# How do you clone a MODEL on Roblox?

Tags: roblox

I have seen videos and stuff on how to clone things in Roblox, but most of it is just "How to clone parts in Roblox!" and "How to clone OBJECTS in Roblox!" But still  is only showing parts. My goal here is to make a system that when you touch a part, your character gets cloned to a position in the workspace, while a cut scene plays. This is like the system used in Mini Toon's game "Piggy" that broke records. I do not need help with any of the cut scene things though, I got that covered.

```
wait(10)
copy = game.Workspace.YourUsernameHere:clone()
copy.Parent = game.Workspace
copy.Name = "Test"
copy.Posistion = Vector3.new(0, 0, 0)
```

This is one of the things I have seen. I hope someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Archivable property must be set to true in order to clone the player's `Character`.

```
wait(10)

game.Workspace.YourUsernameHere.Archivable = true
copy = game.Workspace.YourUsernameHere:clone()
game.Workspace.YourUsernameHere.Archivable = false

copy.Parent = game.Workspace

copy.Name = "Test"

copy:MoveTo(Vector3.new(0, 0, 0))
```

Comment: - create an empty game and copy that script into a LocalScript in StarterPlayerScripts. Replace "YourUsernameHere" with your user's name. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Model:SetPrimaryPartCFrame()`

Comment: How would I use it though?

Comment: This is a great example of why it's useful to offer explanation with answers, instead of just code. Explanation can help provide context. Otherwise, you often just end up with follow-up questions. Can you edit your answer to provide additional context and reasoning?